# CNAME entry not working on NameCheap using Amazon Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, web-hosting, namecheap

I am trying to set up a few SSL certificates in Amazon Certificate Manager, but I am trouble getting them verified after adding the CNAME in Namecheap.

[Here](https://s8.postimg.cc/lers5lwn9/AWS_Certificate_Manager-_DNS.png) is an example of the CNAME verification entries at Amazon Certificate Manager

[Here](https://s8.postimg.cc/n6kr0gaud/Name_Cheap-_CNAME.png) is an example of another domains CNAME entry at Namecheap

If I put the entire value of the ***Name*** entry into ***Host*** at Namecheap, the verification fails. I also get an error on some long domains I have, as the ***Name*** entry exceeds 60 characters.

Can anyone assist with the correct parts needed to verify via DNS using Namecheap?

Comment: The input from the images differs, try to use same input not prefixing it with `http`

Comment: Remove the domain name and the final dot, e.g.  `_cfff00000.www.example.com` the value on the left is just `_cfff00000.www`.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In the CNAME record enter - `_cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2` as the host field and - `_490287b8f448e2cca3862ebb4a51591.acm-validations.aws` in the value field.

Once done wait for at least 1 hour for the changes to reflect.

Comment: Hello, on NameCheaps site we are given a Record Type field, Host field, and Target field. In this example Record Type field is obviously CNAME. Are you saying that the Host field should be _cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2 and the target should be _490287b8f448e2cca3862ebb4a51591.acm-validations.aws.xxxxx? Also does the xxxxx stand for my domain name? So if my domain name was www.blah.com it should be _490287b8f448e2cca3862ebb4a51591.acm-validations.aws.www.blah.com?

Comment: no you don't need to replace xxx with your domain name, I had added that for if any more extra string for general use case.  Now I have updated the answer. You have to enter till .aws only.

Comment: the underscore in the value gives an error - has anybody faced something similar ?

Comment: @apratimankur https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html : simply remove the underscore, and it should still validate

Comment: below one worked for me i had to add ".www" at the end of the CNAME record or I didn't work

Comment: Solution below (add '.www' at the end) also worked for me :)

Answer (score 67):

If anyone is looking for NameCheap DNS record validation for AWS CloudFront ssl validation then please refer screenshot below. This NameCheap DNS record validation  worked for me as of Jul 2019

[image: Cname record AWS and NameCheap]

Comment: This is confusing: I can't edit the value on AWS, so why does the image say "remove domain at the end"? the guids for name and value don't match, so it can't be that

Comment: @jcollum Ah I see , screen shot was little confusing. I meant  "remove domain at the end" in DNS record in NameCheap, not in AWS. I have updated the screen shot now.

Comment: I went through setting up a static site with namecheap recently and they said the `ALIAS,@, [aws url]` record was very important too. I'm recalling that from memory so I could be a little off. Worth bringing up for anyone else who has to go through this.

Comment: ok this finally makes sense and I feel silly. When you use xyz.mysite.com in the host field you are actually setting a record for "xyz.mysite.com.mysite.com".

Comment: The namecheap website crashes if I try to append .www at the end of the host field. As soon as I type '.' the whole website freezes for some reason. I can't complete my validation this way

Comment: @Suhas The same happened to me, and I solved it by reopening it in firefox and pasting it. It still froze but waiting a little pasted it, but in chrome it always crashed

Comment: The same applies for SendGrid and other CNAME verifications, as well.

Comment: For me I copied and pasted what amazon gave me (in firefox) and deleted the domain and period from the end. I didn't have to add the .www at the end.

Comment: Thank you! I spent like 30 min trying to paste this into Namecheap because their site is terrible and kept crashing when the Host value was too long. They should really make that clearer.

Answer (score 48):

Adding a more complete answer.

Some DNS provider like Namecheap appends the [bare domain name](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9642/67/difference-between-bare-domainwww-in-the-csr) to the DNS record. In effect, if you add the full record provided from Amazon Certificate Manager like so (replace `example.com` with your domain):

```
_cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2.example.com
```

What you'll end up with is

```
_cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2.example.com.example.com
```

To check if this is the case, after you have added the DNS record, run this command (on Unix)

```
dig +short _cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2.example.com.example.com
```

If it returns the CNAME record, you have to omit the domain name from your DNS record so you won't get a duplicate domain name in there. Then run

```
dig +short _cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2.example.com
```

You should get the corresponding CNAME record from it. The validation can take up to 48 hours.

Comment: This should be the correct answer since it explain what actually happens in the background. Thanks!

Comment: Also most helpful to me - dig is a much faster way to check for correctness than waiting 30 mins for amazon to check it

Comment: Fantastic answer. I used `dig` and found that Namecheap as of this writing does exactly what you described.

Answer (score 12):

Even though AWS includes it,  do not include the domain name itself in the CNAME Host field for Namecheap (they apparently append it for you);  just chop that off at the end. The value field is fine.

Give it half an hour.

Answer (score 4):

For any one using a subdomain like - `api.example.com`.

In the CNAME record enter - `_cff0cdhash.api` as the host field and - `_490287b8f4hash.acm-validations.aws` in the value field. As namecheap itself appends `example.com` to it. I was not able to figure out a way to make it work for `www.api.example.com`.

Answer (score 3):

`namecheap.com` does now allow a leading underscore in the Value field.

As specified in the AWS docs' [Troubleshoot DNS Validation Problems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html) ,

> you can remove the underscore from the ACM-provided value and validate your domain without it.

In your case, the Value would be:

> 490287b8f448e2cca3862ebb4a51591.acm-validations.aws.

Where the trailing dot should still be permitted.

Comment: Namecheap does allow leading underscore in the value field, where are you getting your information from?

Comment: @JoshuaUgba By using Namecheap

Comment: I created a CNAME record with a leading underscore value and it worked just fine, and it was validated by AWS today.

Comment: @JoshuaUgba Hm, good to know. Perhaps Namecheap started allowing them recently. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html#underscores-prohibited and the conversation from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51208517/7954504 for background

Answer (score 0):

above worked for me except for the root domain validation ; there I had to add entire string _cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2.example.com
instead of _cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2. for the certificate to be issued.
For the others, _cff0cda88701846cbe7a34cd737378e2.www was enough. Hope it helps. Just did this today.